# MariaDB subquery use whole row

Tags: mysql, mariadb, subquery

Usually subqueries compare single or multiple fields and delete statements usually delete values by an ID. Unfortunately I don't have a ID field and I have to use an generic approach for differnt kind of tables.
That's why I am working with a subquery using limit and offset as resolving rows.

I know that approach is risky, however is there any way to delete rows by subquerying and comparing the whole row?

```
DELETE FROM table WHERE * = ( SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1 OFFSET 6 )
```

I am using the latest version of MariaDB

Comment: No you cannot use an * in a where clause and limit without order by is unsafe other than that I am unclear what you are trying to do

Comment: You can't use the solution you posted "as is". Can you include a few rows of sample data to understan the problem better? Maybe there's a trick that can be used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a really strange need, but who am I to judge? :)

I would simply rely on the primary key:

`DELETE FROM table WHERE id_table = (SELECT id_table FROM table LIMIT 1 OFFSET 6)`

update: oh, so you don't have a primary key? You can join on the whole row this way (assuming it has five columns named a, b, c, d, e):

```
DELETE t
FROM table t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a, b, c, d, e
    FROM table
    ORDER BY a, b, c, d, e
    LIMIT 1 OFFSET 6
) ROW6 USING (a, b, c, d, e);
```

Any subset of columns (e.g. a, c, d) that uniquely identify a row will do the trick (and is probably what you need as a primary key anyway).

Edit: Added an `ORDER BY` clause as per The Impaler's excellent advice. That's what you get for knocking an example up quickly.

Comment: Oh wow that looks like the exact strange thing i am looking for :) will test by todays evening. Thx for the input so far!

Comment: `LIMIT` / `OFFSET` without `ORDER BY` rarely makes sense.

Comment: is the same possible with '*' logic? DELETE t
FROM table t
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT * FROM table LIMIT 1 OFFSET 6
) ROW6 USING ('*');

Comment: Offhand, I don't thing `USING(*)` is legal syntax. You will probably need to use the `information_schema.columns` table to contruct the column names dynamically.

Answer (score -1):

```
DELETE FROM t
    ORDER BY ...  -- fill in as needed
    LIMIT 6
```

(Works on any version)

Comment: this has nothing to do with whole row comparison, neither with subqueries